# Textpad search all regex

Tags: regex, textpad

Is there a possibility to "search all" in Textpad (or with some other text-editor)?

Because I only want the numbers of addresses:

- *StreetTest **98***
- *StreetTestB **5A***

So I use the search regex:   **[0-9].*$**

But textpad gives the results one by one. (and it's a file of 4000 entries...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get Visual Studio 2010, it has a Find In Files search option that will return a clickable list of all results (double clicking will take you to the line). If you expand the options for the search, it has a place to enter a Regular Expression.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was:

EditPad Pro 7 (free trail):

Search => List All Matches

Search => Copy Matches